# A valid formula or a list of values must be less than or equal to 255 characters

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi for generating excel file. I need a dropdown which contains a big list. I have made it. It is working fine at my ubuntu libra office and google sheets. But when I am trying use that xlsx file then dropdown is missing. After updating my poi version into 5.0.0 I got this error

> A valid formula or a list of values must be less than or equal to 255
> characters (including separators).

I want to bypass this problem.

Here is my code

```java
Cell cell14 = row.createCell(14);
cell14.setCellValue("Variation - Size");
cell14.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
VariationName sizeVariationName = variationNameFacility.get(2L);
List<VariationValue> sizeVariationValues = variationValueFacility.findByVariationName(sizeVariationName);

DataValidationHelper sizeValidationHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
String[] sizeList = sizeVariationValues.stream()
                    .map(value -> value.getValue().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " ") + " - (" + value.getId() + ")")
                    .toArray(String[]::new);

DataValidationConstraint sizeValidationConstraint = sizeValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(processStringArray(sizeList));
 CellRangeAddressList sizeAddressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 150, 14, 14);
DataValidation sizeValidation = sizeValidationHelper.createValidation(sizeValidationConstraint, sizeAddressList);
            sheet.addValidationData(sizeValidation);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How is your question related to `spring` or `spring-boot`? Please remove the misleading tags, thanks!

Comment: ok i have remvoed it thanks

Comment: This error is likely caused by the length of the sizeAddressList string being too long (over 255 characters)

Comment: yes, in my list there is more than 200 string. How can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A valid formula or a list of values must be less than or equal to 255 characters (including separators)." is an Excel limitation.

In your code the code line

```
DataValidationConstraint sizeValidationConstraint = sizeValidationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(processStringArray(sizeList));
```

creates a list of values delimited by comma from the given string array. If the length of that list gets greater than 255, then this approach is not usable.

The approach which is independent of list length is to have the list items in cells of a separate sheet and have a named range pointing to that cell range. Then [DataValidationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationHelper.html#createFormulaListConstraint-java.lang.String-) can be used where `String listFormula` is the name of that named range.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

public class CreateExcelDataValidationListNamedRange {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
   int count = 100;
   String[] listItems = new String[count];
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    listItems[i] = "Item " + (i+1);  
   }
   
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  

   //create sheet for storing the list items:
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ListSheet");
   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("List items");
   int r = 1;
   for (String listItem : listItems) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r); r++;
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(listItem);
   }
   //create a named range usable as list constraint
   Name namedRange = workbook.createName();
   namedRange.setNameName("ListItems");
   String reference = "ListSheet!$A$2:$A$" + r;
   namedRange.setRefersToFormula(reference);

   sheet.setSelected(false);

   //create sheet for using the data validation lists
   sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
   
   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(14).setCellValue("List cells below");
   
   DataValidationHelper dataValidationHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
   // following creates formula pointing to named range "ListItems"
   DataValidationConstraint dataValidationConstraint = dataValidationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("ListItems");
   CellRangeAddressList cellRangeAddressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 150, 14, 14);
   DataValidation dataValidation = dataValidationHelper.createValidation(dataValidationConstraint, cellRangeAddressList);
   sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

   //hide the ListSheet
   //workbook.setSheetHidden(0, true);
   //set Sheet1 active
   workbook.setActiveSheet(1);

   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelDataValidationListNamedRange.xlsx");
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
   workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Using `workbook.setSheetHidden(0, true);` one can hide the list sheet. After that, it will not be visible to normal users.